# Html/Php input type filed tags/list

Tags: php, html, css

Is there a input type in html which is similar to the tag input file in stackoverflow or youtube
I want, that the user can add like 5 strings (or tags).

I hope you can help me...

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: No currently i am just working with html,php and css

Comment: Please share more details - how is an upload button similar to a text field where you could input five strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following library for multiple tags. It's Awesome.

https://select2.org/tagging

You need to add jquery CDN in your HTML.